# using Prolog for deductive database

Tags: database, prolog

I started learning prolog,here is where i am stuck,
I have a deductive db as follows,

```
employee(smith, accounting, 30000).
employee(jones, accounting, 50000).
employee(mary, accounting, 40000).
employee(helen, payroll, 20000).
employee(mike, payroll, 10000).
department(accounting, jones, 3).
department(payroll, helen, 2).
```

I need a Prolog predicate, manager_higherSalary_biggerDept, , to find the names of employees who have salary more than 40000 and are managing departments with more employees than a given department.

For example, to find manager of departments of size greater than payroll that make more than 40000 a year, the query:

```
?- manager_higherSalary_biggerDept(M, 40000, payroll).
```

Should give: M= jones;
             no

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: actually, your db it's not - yet - a deductive db...

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward (not tested):

```
manager_higherSalary_biggerDept(Name, SalaryThreshold, DeptName) :-
    employee(Name, _, Salary),
    Salary > SalaryThreshold,
    department(DeptName, _, DeptThreshold),
    department(_, Name, Dept),
    Dept > DeptThreshold.
```

Answer (score 0):

Prolog is a *declarative language*. That means you describe the solution to the problem and let its inference engine do the work. So...

```
manager_of_bigger_department_with_higher_salary( M , S , D ) :- %
  department(D,_,DS) ,                                          % get the size of the targer department
  manages_department_larger_than(M,DS) ,                        % find the manager of a larger department
  has_higher_salary_than(M,S)                                   % who has a salary higher than the specified threshold
  .                                                             % 

manages_department_larger_than( M , D , T ) :-
  department(D,M,S) ,
  S > T
  .

has_salary_higher_than( E , T ) :-
  employee(E,_,S) ,
  S > T
  .
```